# (PHP/JQuery) Populating form with data?

Tags: php, jquery

```
populate_form($array_data)
{
   //Format: $array_data['css_selector'] = "value";

    $html = "<script>\n$(document).ready(function(){\n";

    foreach($array_data as $key => $val)
    {
        $html .= "$('$key').val('$val');\n";
    }

    $html .= "});\n</script>";

    return $html;
}
```

I just coded this function but havent used it yet. 
I wonder if this is approach for populating form with data is a good idea.

Comment: why not populate the markup and avoid the extra step of having Jquery do it?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't do it this way.

If you want to populate a form, populate it. Don't overkill and make something *else* which populates it.

I mean, you already control the output of the HTML, why not just do it directly and not drag jQuery into this?

Comment: Because I have form html file that serves for both inserting and editing data. And with this jquery trick, I can populate the form without having to create another file for editing data. For example: <?php if($form_edit){ populate_form($data); } ?>

Comment: What do you mean by that? You shouldn't *need* to do that. If you are printing raw HTML, that's something you should fix. I always use a XML parser to create my forms (if they are large). Post your other code.

Comment: Can you show me an example of that XML parser that creates your forms?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can assign values from PHP to JavaScript/jQuery in following way:

```
populate_form($array_data)
{
   //Format: $array_data['css_selector'] = "value";

    foreach($array_data as $key => $val)
    {
    ?>    
        <script language="javascript">
        $('<?php echo $key ?>').val('<?php echo $val ?>');
        </script>
    <?php
    }

    return $html;
}
```